# Socket gets changed to false when pass it to another thread

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

So I have a simple class like this:

```
class Server {
    private $Socket;

    public function __construct(string $ipAddress = "127.0.0.1", int $port = 1757) {
        $socket = $this->createSocket();
        $socket = $this->bindSocket($socket, $ipAddress, $port);
        $this->Socket = $socket;
    }

    private function createSocket() {
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        return $socket;
    }

    private function bindSocket($socket, string $ipAddress, int $port) {
        socket_bind($socket, $ipAddress, $port);
        socket_listen($socket);
        return $socket;
    }

    public function startServer() {
        $WebserverCallable = function(array $socket) {
            while(($client = socket_accept($socket[0]))) {
                $client[] = new Client($this->Router);
            }
        };

        $WebserverStart = new ThreadCreator($WebserverCallable, [$this->Socket]);
        var_dump($WebserverStart);

        $WebserverStart->start();
    }
}
```

And the, another class is the following:

```
class ThreadCreator extends \Thread {
    private $ToPerform;
    private $arguments;

    public function __construct(callable $ToPerform, array $arguments) {
        $this->ToPerform = $ToPerform;
        $this->arguments = (array) $arguments;
    }

    public function run() {
        $ToPerform = $this->ToPerform;
        return $ToPerform($this->arguments);
    }
}
```

When I call it with something like this:

```
$Server = new Server();
$Server->startServer();
```

The output is:

```
class Leloutama\lib\Core\Server\ThreadCreator#5 (2) {
  public $ToPerform =>
  class Closure#6 (1) {
    public $parameter =>
    array(1) {
      '$socket' =>
      string(10) "<required>"
    }
  }
  public $arguments =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Why does the socket resource turn into `false`? I have already debugged the code
and confirmed it that `$this->Socket` holds a legit resource...

Comment: `socket_accept` accepts a single `socket` whereas in your code `$socket[0]` seems like you are referencing an array of sockets, although it is not wrong, but I can't see `$socket` array in your code.

Comment: As in `$WebserverStart = new ThreadCreator($WebserverCallable, [$this->Socket]);` I do pass an array, that is - `[$this->Socket]`

Comment: then there is difference in the case. `$Socket` is not same as `$socket`

Comment: Umm... I think you got it wrong.... Why should there be any problem with the case, `$this->Socket` is a property in the class, and I'm passing it as an argument, so.... The case shouldn't be any matter at all... And if the case was a matter shouldn't the property `$arguments` won't get set in ThreadCreator. Isn't it?